# How to find divergence of $f(\vec{r})\vec{r}$

Tags: vector-analysis

I have to find $$\mathrm{div}f(\vec{r})\vec{r}$$
I only know that $\mathrm{r}$ is a motion vector so it should be $\vec{r} = \{x;y;z\}$ and also that $\mathrm{div} = \left(\vec{\nabla},f(r)\vec{r}\right)$ but I do not know how to handle $f(r)\vec{r}$ there properly to substitute it into determinant.

Comment: What is $r$ in $f(r)$?  Should that be $f(\vec r)$?

Comment: The real question is: does $f(\vec r)$ only depend on the radial coordinate, or does it depend on the angular coordinates as well? In other words, if $f(\vec r)$ rotationally symmetric?

Comment: well, it seem to be correct, by the way, seems like a typo in the book, because scalar $r$ is not given

Comment: So does $f(\vec r)$ depend only on $r$, or does it depend on $r, \theta$ and $\phi$?

Comment: What is your definition of divergence?

Comment: @KennyWong, only on $r$

Comment: @KennyWong I think that there is some confusion in this conversation.  In the OP's setting, $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ is the position vector.  In what you wrote, you're using $r$, $\theta$, $\phi$ as in spherical coordinates.  So, $\vec{r}$ does depend on $r$, $\theta$, $\phi$, but it is confusing because you and the OP are using $r$ and $\vec{r}$ as two very different concepts (and they're getting conflated).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sure. Though I believe that, by the end of this conversion, both the OP and I agreed to use the vector $\vec r$ to refer to the position vector and the scalar $r$ to refer to the radial coordinate! At least, I hope that's the case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. $\vec{r}=\{x,y,z\}$, in other words, $\vec{r}$ is a position vector.
2. $f(\vec{r})$ is a real-valued function.
3. $f(\vec{r})\vec{r}$ is a vector-valued function, where $\vec{r}$ is scaled by $f(\vec{r})$.  In other words, $f(\vec{r})\vec{r}=(f(\vec{r})x,f(\vec{r})y,f(\vec{r})z)$.
4. The question asks for $\operatorname{div}(f(\vec{r})\vec{r})$ (there are no parentheses in the original post).

Since $f(\vec{r})\vec{r}=(f(\vec{r})x,f(\vec{r})y,f(\vec{r})z)$, 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{div}(f(\vec{r})\vec{r})&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(\vec{r})x+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(\vec{r})y+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(\vec{r})z\\
&=3f(\vec{r})+f_x(\vec{r})x+f_y(\vec{r})y+f_z(\vec{r})z
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standard vector calculus identity: $$\nabla.(f \vec A) = (\nabla f). \vec A + f (\nabla . \vec A).$$

You can use this to get
$$ \nabla (f\vec r) = (\nabla f). \vec r + f (\nabla . \vec r).$$

But $\nabla . \vec r = 3$, so this reduces to
$$ \nabla (f \vec r) = (\nabla f) . \vec r + 3f.$$

---

It might be good to rederive the same result in spherical polar coordinates. First, you write $\vec r$ as $r \vec e_r$, where $r$ is the radial coordinate in your spherical coordinate system, and $\vec e_r$ is a *unit* vector pointing radially outwards. So $f(\vec r) \vec r = rf(r,\theta, \phi) \vec e_r$.

Using the formula for [del in spherical polars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula), we have
$$ \nabla . (rf(r, \theta, \phi) \vec e_r) = \frac 1 {r^2} \frac{\partial (r^3 f(r,\theta, \phi))}{\partial r},$$
and you should be able to verify that this agrees with the earlier result.

In fact, since $f$ only depends on the radial coordinate $r$ in your example, you can change the partial derivative to an ordinary derivative:
$$ \nabla . (rf(r) \vec e_r) = \frac 1 {r^2} \frac{d(r^3 f(r))}{dr}.$$